# Book on the history of Darwin's discoveries and development of his theory

Tags: natural-selection, literature, book-recommendation, history, speciation

This question is a book request. I am wondering if there are any books with these elements:

- Tells the history of Darwin's discoveries.
- Captures Darwin's changing views of the origins of species, because of his discoveries and his thinking on the subject.
- Is a modern text but incorporates some of Darwin's writings (e.g. from [the Voyage of the Beagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Voyage_of_the_Beagle), etc).

---

<sup>Note: I am *not* asking for a book that is just explaining the process of natural selection, rather I am looking for a historical book about Darwin's discoveries and the [inception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception_of_Darwin%27s_theory) and [development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_of_Darwin%27s_theory)  and eventually his [publication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publication_of_Darwin%27s_theory) of his theory of natural selection.</sup>

Comment: On your second point, for the most part, Darwin's views were fully formed within a few years of his return from the Beagle. They didn't really slowly change. But he was slow to publish for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @KarlKjer While that is somewhat true, I think there is a lot of nuance missing from that description, and Darwin certainly wavered on things and shifted his views prior to that time; the slow publication is only one aspect of the story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain it fills every element of your question, but I really enjoyed Michael Ruse's "The Darwinian Revolution: Science Red in Tooth and Claw."

It's especially good for setting up the collection of worldviews that predated Darwin, and the influence on him by both biologists/anatomists as well as very crucially geologists like Charles Lyell (Darwin really thought of himself more as a geologist; the long time prior to publishing *Origin* was largely because he was trying to build up some scientific chops as a biologist).

The aspect it is most likely to lack is references to original source material from Darwin. While it certainly draws on such writings, I don't recall it actually containing reproductions of those writings, at least not on a substantial basis.

Importantly, however, this book *is not a biography* - it is a history of the scientific community at the time, centered around Darwin and *Origin* and placing them in relevant context.

Comment: Thanks a lot (+1). To not discourage others from answering, I will wait some time before accepting.